# when outputting rspec to file in documentation format, how do I insert newlines?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am outputting rspec documentation to a file and want it to be in markdown (e.g. the top level requirements have a #, the other context have ##), but markdown needs to have a newline between headers to make it more readable.

Is there a way to do that?  Or any other way to make the output a readable form of documentation for the intended specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do this with an RSpec [custom formatter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters). E.g.:

```
class MarkdownFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started

  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def example_started(notification)
    @output << "# Heading\n" << "## " << notification.example.description << "\n"
  end
end
```

Save into `specs/markdown_formatter.rb`, then:

```
$ rspec --format MarkdownFormatter
```

You might need to dig into the rspec-core gem code to figure out how the formatters work. I'd recommend looking at the "documentation" formatter (the one that is used when you provide the option `--format doc`)

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I was looking for. But hopefully not need to dig into the actual gem.